# Based on a condition, how to remove an item from the processed array and move it to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter, splice

I have two arrays in my react component as follows ...

```
const [Selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
const [NonSelected, setNonSelected] = React.useState([]);

const Tmp_Selected = [
  { "Metric": "AAA", "Weight": 10, "Value": "xxx" },
  { "Metric": "BBB", "Weight": 20, "Value": "xx1" },
  { "Metric": "CCC", "Weight": 30, "Value": "xx2" },
];
const Tmp_NonSelected = [
  { "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "yy" },
  { "Metric": "EEE", "Weight": 15, "Value": "zz" },
  { "Metric": "FFF", "Weight": 25, "Value": "cc" },
];

React.useEffect(() => {
  setSelected(Tmp_Selected);
  setNonSelected(Tmp_NonSelected);
}, [location]);
```

There is a function which gets passed just `Metric` and `Weight` related values. Based on that I need to move each object which matches both criteria from the `NonSelected` to the `Selected` array.

```
const MoveValues = (Metric='DDD', Weight=5) => {
  
}
```

The expected result for the above two default measures is equal to this ...

```
const Tmp_Selected = [
   { "Metric": "AAA", "Weight": 10, "Value": "xxx" },
   { "Metric": "BBB", "Weight": 20, "Value": "xx1" },
   { "Metric": "CCC", "Weight": 30, "Value": "xx2" },
   { "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "yy" },
];
const Tmp_NonSelected = [
   { "Metric": "EEE", "Weight": 15, "Value": "zz" },
   { "Metric": "FFF", "Weight": 25, "Value": "cc" },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature the OP actually relies on for solving the task is an array mutating `reject` functionality.

Such a function (or method) does accept a callback similar to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), where the callback's parameters are `item, idx, arr, ...`, and its return value is expected to be a boolean type or at least truthy/falsy. Upon the result of each invocation of the callback, while iterating the to be operated array entirely, a `reject` implementation will [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) each matching item from the operated array, thus mutating the latter. Each spliced item gets collected in the implementation's `result` array which also is the `reject` function's return value.

Thus, a possible implementation of the OP's `moveValues` function can be accomplished as easy as this ...

```js
const tmpSelected = [
  { "Metric": "AAA", "Weight": 10, "Value": "xxx" },
  { "Metric": "BBB", "Weight": 20, "Value": "xx1" },
  { "Metric": "CCC", "Weight": 30, "Value": "xx2" },
];
const tmpNonSelected = [
  { "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "yy" },
  { "Metric": "EEE", "Weight": 15, "Value": "zz" },
  { "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "aa" },
  { "Metric": "FFF", "Weight": 25, "Value": "cc" },
  { "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "bb" },
];

const moveItems = (metric, weight) => {
  tmpSelected
    .push(
      ...reject(tmpNonSelected, item => {

        return item.Metric === metric && item.Weight === weight;
      }),
    );
};
moveItems('DDD', 5);

console.log({ tmpSelected, tmpNonSelected });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
function reject(target, condition) {
  const result = [];

  let idx = target.length;
  const copy = [...target];

  // - Processing the `target` array from RIGHT to LEFT
  //   keeps the `idx` always in sync with both related
  //   array items, the one of the mutated and also the
  //   one of the unmutated `copy` of the processed array
  //   reference.
  // - Thus, `condition` always gets passed the unmutated
  //   shallow `copy`.

  while (idx) {
    if (
      // - take a *sparse array* into account.
      target.hasOwnProperty(--idx) &&

      // - keep processing the unmutated array.
      condition(copy[idx], idx, copy)
    ) {
      // - keep filling the `result` array with each
      //   *rejected* item FROM its LEFT side while
      //   mutating the `target` array.
      result.unshift(target.splice(idx, 1)[0]);
    }
  }
  // - returns an array of rejected items, but not the
  //   processed and mutated `target` array reference.
  return result;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method of Arrays to remove object from the nonSelected Array.

1. Find the object to move
2. remove object from nonSelected array using filter
3. Add object into selected array using spread operator
4. setState of both the objects

```js
const MoveValues = (Metric = 'DDD', Weight = 5) => {

    const objectToMove = NonSelected.find(object => object.Metric === Metric && object.Weight === Weight);
  
    if (objectToMove) {

      const arrayOfNonSelected = NonSelected.filter(obj => obj !== objectToMove);
  
      const arrayOfSelected = [...Selected, objectToMove];
  
      setNonSelected(arrayOfNonSelected);
      setSelected(updatedSelected);
    }

  }
```

Comment: What happens, if there is/are more than just one object in `Tmp_NonSelected` which do/es match the `Metric` and `Weight` values?

Comment: `const objectToMove = NonSelected.find(object => object.Metric === Metric && object.Weight === Weight);` Will return the first object it finds matching the Metric and Weight, and in `arrayOfNonSelected` the found object will be removed, If the Object containing the same Metric And weight have the third field - Value also to be the same, Then filter will remove out all the objects matching.

Comment: In case of other array items than just `{ "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "yy" }`, like `{ "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "aa" }`and e.g. another `{ "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "bb" }`, one wants to move the latter two items as well and not just omit them, which is, what the `find` and `filter` approach does. But one could achieve the OP's goal of `moveItems` (plural) by changing the initial `find` to a `filter` as well.

Comment: Yes a `filter` and `filter` would do the triclk, but would look a little messy. Using the `...reject` would seem like a better approach. Been off js for sometime now, so a lil rusty :P

Answer (score 0):

```
const MoveValues = (Metric = 'DDD', Weight = 5) => {
      const item_Selecteds = NonSelected.filter(item => item.Metric === Metric && item.Weight === Weight)
      const Tmp_Selected = [...Selected, ...item_Selected]
      const Tmp_NonSelected = NonSelected.filter(item => item.Metric !== Metric && item.Weight !== Weight)

      console.log(Tmp_NonSelected)
      console.log(Tmp_Selected)
}
```

Comment: What happens, if there is/are more than just one object in `Tmp_NonSelected` which do/es match the `Metric` and `Weight` values?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code of your Component:

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function StackTest() {
    const [Selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
    const [NonSelected, setNonSelected] = React.useState([]);

    const Tmp_Selected = [
        { "Metric": "AAA", "Weight": 10, "Value": "xxx" },
        { "Metric": "BBB", "Weight": 20, "Value": "xx1" },
        { "Metric": "CCC", "Weight": 30, "Value": "xx2" },
    ];
    const Tmp_NonSelected = [
        { "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "yy" },
        { "Metric": "EEE", "Weight": 15, "Value": "zz" },
        { "Metric": "FFF", "Weight": 25, "Value": "cc" },
    ];
    useEffect(() => {
        setSelected(Tmp_Selected);
        setNonSelected(Tmp_NonSelected);
    }, []);

    const MoveValues = (Metric = '', Weight = 0) => {
        const objectToMove = NonSelected.find(object => object.Metric === Metric && object.Weight === Weight);
        // console.log(NonSelected.find(object => object.Metric === Metric && object.Weight === Weight),"objectToMove");
        if (objectToMove) {
            const arrNonSelected = NonSelected.filter(obj => obj !== objectToMove);
            const arrSelected = [...Selected, objectToMove];
            setNonSelected(arrNonSelected);
            setSelected(arrSelected);
        }
    }
    const MoveBackValues = (Metric = '', Weight = 0) => {
        const objectToMove = Selected.find(object => object.Metric === Metric && object.Weight === Weight);
        // console.log(Selected.find(object => object.Metric === Metric && object.Weight === Weight),"objectToMove");
        if (objectToMove) {
            const arrSelected = Selected.filter(obj => obj !== objectToMove);
            const arrNonSelected = [...NonSelected, objectToMove];
            setSelected(arrSelected);
            setNonSelected(arrNonSelected);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        <h1>Selected</h1>
        {Selected && Selected.map((item,index) => (
            <p key={index} onClick={(e) => {
                MoveBackValues(item.Metric, item.Weight)
            }
            }>
            {item.Metric} - {item.Value} - {item.Weight}
            <br/></p>
        ))}
        <h1>NonSelected</h1>
        {NonSelected && NonSelected.map((item,index) => (
            <p key={index} onClick={(e) => {
                MoveValues(item.Metric, item.Weight)
            }
            }>
            {item.Metric} - {item.Value} - {item.Weight}
            <br/></p>
        ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default StackTest
```

Comment: What happens, if there is/are more than just one object in `Tmp_NonSelected` which do/es match the `Metric` and `Weight` values?

Comment: In that case, your first occured pair will be moved to the selected object.
It's a desire-based scenario, what do you need as output for multiple occurrences?

Comment: In case of other array items than just `{ "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "yy" }`, like `{ "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "aa" }`and e.g. another `{ "Metric": "DDD", "Weight": 5, "Value": "bb" }`, one wants to move the latter two items as well and not just omit them, which is, what the `find` and `filter` approach does. But one could achieve the OP's goal of `moveItems` (plural) by changing the initial `find` to a `filter` as well.